# Electronegativity comparison of group 13 elements

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why is electronegativity of indium slightly  greater than gallium?

Comment: Because measurement says so.

Comment: Electronegativity is a human construct; it isn't a fundamental physical property of an element. We often like to use electronegativity to explain stuff, which is great when there is a clear-cut difference. So, for example, in LiH you have negative H and positive Li. Here it is not quite so clear-cut: some scales have In more electronegative than Ga and some scales have Ga more electronegative. (This aspect of your question really needs some clarification, btw.) What's the answer? Probably "we don't know", since it depends on what formula you use for this "electronegativity" thingum.